# Исправить простую ошибку в JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var num = 20;

$('.class').css('transform', 'translateX(num * 2px));
```

Как сделать так, чтоб в class записалось уже готовое свойство:

```
transform: translateX(40px);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var num = 20;
$('.class').css('transform', 'translateX(' + (num * 2) + 'px)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы могли описывать трансформацию чем-то похожим на `'transform', 'translateX(num * 2px)'`, если бы `num * 2px` являлось функцией css3, и только, если бы переменная `num` объявлялась непосредственно в css.

Т.к. `num` является переменной javascript, то ее, как и оператор умножения, нужно отделять кавычками:

```js
var num = 20;

$('.class').css('transform', 'translateX(' + (num * 2) + 'px)');
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Вариант с [css переменными](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) + функция [`calc()`](https://webref.ru/css/value/calc)

```js
$('.class').css('transform', 'translateX(calc(var(--num)*2))');
```

```css
:root {
  --num: 20px;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Поддержка браузерами css переменных - [тут](http://caniuse.com/#search=variables).
Поддержка браузерами функции calc() - [тут](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc()).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num = 20;

$('.class').css('transform', 'translateX('+(num * 2)+'px)');
```

```css
.class {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:#f1f1f1;
box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Comment: И чем же ваш ответ отличается от предыдущих 2х?)

Comment: Ничем, другого метода лучше нету. А вариант с `--var` костыли.